# Do I need to use the ARIA role attribute on custom radio buttons to be compliant with accessibility guidelines?

Tags: html, wai-aria, wcag

I have the following HTML to create a custom radio button that appears like a yes/no toggle. To comply with WCAG guidelines, would this markup require a `role="checkbox"` ARIA attribute on the label? Because I have a native HTML radio button in the markup, I'm not sure if ARIA is required here.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" class="form-control">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" selected="true">No
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you hiding the input in JS such as label > input[type="radio"] {display: none;} and then adding custom CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, radio buttons are fine as is.  There's nothing custom about them.  You are using a native radio button and the role is defined by default and you have an implicit label associated with it.

If you set the role to `checkbox`, that would cause the screen reader to announce it as a checkbox and the user would think they could press <kbd>space</kbd> to toggle the value on/off, which is not the case.  The user **must** hear that it's a radio button so that they'll know to use the arrow keys to navigate to each radio button.

Two things are missing, though:

1. The first is the `name` attribute on each `<input type="radio">` so that the radio buttons are grouped together.
2. The second is a container for the radio buttons (radio group).  You either need a `<fieldset>` or `<div role="radiogroup">`.  Whichever one you choose, the group needs a label.  Either `<legend>` or `aria-label`, respectively.